# Issue with updating custom field and calling flow using aura components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a custom button in a record page and I want to call a flow I built and refresh a custom field I created on the opportunity line item in the opportunity page using the same custom button I created. I am posting my code here.
ab.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <!--<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>-->
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
    <lightning:button label="CallForceRefresh" onclick="{!c.callme}"/>
</aura:component>
```

abController.js

```
({
    callme : function (component,event,helper) {
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        flow.startFlow("updatereconopp");
           helper.helperMethod();
    },
})
```

abHelper.js

```
({
    helperMethod : function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`lightning:flow` had a action attribute [onstatuschange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/components_using_flow_onfinish.htm) , so it'll fire the action when ever flow behavior changes, you don't need to use `window.location.reload(true)`. for refreshing you can use [refresh view](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation). here sample code snippet for your use case

**cmp**

```
 <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
```

**cmpController**

```
    handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {
   if(event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED_SCREEN" || event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED") {

      $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

   }
}
```